# How to execute jQuery function by webbrowser.InvokeScript?

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, webbrowser-control

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hashbang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/v3.js?beta0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Data pipe
    var datapipe = {
        torrents : {},
        templates:{
            details:function(_){
                var _ = datapipe.torrents["t"+_];
                //console.log("So far so good. Templating.");
                $('#T_comment .btn span').text(_.comment).parent().parent().attr('count',_.comment);
                $('#T_files .btn span').text(_.files);
                return "<a href='download.php/"+_.id+"/"+_.fname+"'><div align=center><img src=/pic/dl.png border=0></div></a><br/>Size: <b>"+_.size+"</b> &nbsp; | &nbsp; Registered: <b>"+_.added+" ago</b> &nbsp; | &nbsp; Seeders: <font color=blue><b>"+_.seed+"</b></font> &nbsp; | &nbsp; Leechers: <font color='red'><b>"+_.leech+"</b></font>"+(_.own ? " &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href='/edit.php?id="+_.id+"'><font color=red><b>[Edit Torrent]</b></font></a>":"")+(_.tool ? " &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a id='free' alt='"+(_.free?2:1)+"'>["+(_.free?"Remove FL!":"Freeleech it!")+"]</a>":"")+"<br><hr><b><font size='3'><font color='blue' id='tname'>"+_.name+"</font>"+(_.free?" <span class='tag"+_.id+" tags free'>Freeleech</span>":"")+"</font></b><hr><div id='desc'>"+_.des+"</div><br/>";
            },
            comment:function(_){
                return "<li class='clearfix comment "+(typeof _.clas !='undefined'?_.clas:'')+"' id='li-comment-"+_.id+"'><div id='comment-"+_.id+"'><img width='100' src='"+_.avatar+"' class='avatar lazy' lazy='yes' /><div class='comment-author'><a href='/userdetails.php?id="+_.uid+"'>"+_.name+"</a>"+(_.donor?"<a href='/donate.php'><img alt='Donor' src='pic/star.gif'></a>":"")+(_.warned?"<img alt='Warned' src='/pic/warned.gif'>":"")+"<div class='tools'>"+(_.uid== 1124468?"<div class='edit' id='"+_.id+"'></div>":"")+"</div></div><div><span class='comment-date'>"+_.added+"</span></div><div class='comment-body'><p>"+_.text+"</p></div></div></li>";
            }
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Details
    detail = {
        show : function(){
            //console.log("TADA!");
            view = true;
            $('#details').show().prev().animate({width:'0px'},(nA?500:1),function(){
                $('#T_back').removeAttr('lock').show().animate({width:'98px'},{duration: (nA?1500:1), easing:'Elastic'});
                $('#T_comment').show().animate({width:'108px'},{duration: (nA?1500:1), easing:'Elastic'});
                if(datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].files)
                    $('#T_files').animate({width:'0px'},(nA?150:1)).show().animate({width:'108px'},{duration: (nA?1500:1), easing:'Elastic'});
                $(this).hide().parent().parent().removeClass('warp');
                $('#T_comment').attr('lock','locked');
                Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=cms&id='+lock+'&c='+$('#T_comment').attr('count'));
                slo = 0;
                $(window).bind('scroll',function(){
                    if ($("#morecommentbtn").offset() && slo < 4)
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($("#morecommentbtn").offset().top-$(window).height())){
                            $('#morecommentbtn a').click();
                            //console.log(slo);
                            if(slo > 3)
                                $(window).unbind('scroll');
                            else
                                slo++;
                        }
                }); 
            });
        },
        back : function(){
            $(window).unbind('scroll');
            //console.log("Back function called!");
            $('#mainBox').addClass('warp');
            $('#T_back').animate({width:'398px',opacity:'0'},(nA?500:1),function(){$(this).css({width:'0px',opacity:'1',display:'none'});});
            $('#T_comment').removeAttr('alt').removeAttr('count').removeAttr('lock').animate({width:'408px',opacity:'0'},(nA?500:1),function(){$(this).css({width:'0px',opacity:'1',display:'none'});});
            if(datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].files)
                $('#T_files').animate({width:'108px'},(nA?150:1)).removeAttr('lock').animate({width:'408px',opacity:'0'},(nA?500:1),function(){$(this).css({width:'0px',opacity:'1',display:'none'});});
            $('#T_table').show().animate({width:'760px'},(nA?500:1),function(){
                $('#details').hide().empty();
                //console.log("scrolled back to :"+ypos+'px');
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:(hashed==2?lpos:ypos)+'px'},(nA?'slow':1),function(){
                    //console.log("highlighted: #tr"+lock);
                    $('#tr'+lock).highlight(0.8);
                    lock = view = 0;
                    if(ypos)
                        lpos = ypos;
                    ypos = 0;
                    hashed = 1;
                    //console.log("lock cleaned");
                });
            });
            //console.log("Done.");
        },
        preview : function(_){
            if(typeof datapipe.torrents["t"+_] == 'undefined')
                window.location.replace('/details.php?id='+_);
            if(datapipe.torrents["t"+_].des != 0){
                //console.log("Found! Making the template!");
                var tempdesc = datapipe.templates.details(_);
                $('#details').empty().html(tempdesc);
                //console.log("Done. Show function excuted.");
                if(hashed == 1)
                    Engine.hash.write('/details.php?id='+_);
                else
                    detail.show();
            }else{
                //console.log("Description not found. Requesting...");
                Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=d&id='+_,1);
            }
            if(!ypos){
                ypos = $(window).scrollTop();
                //console.log("scrolled up from: "+ypos);{duration: 1000, easing: method2}
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#mainBox").offset().top}, (nA?'slow':1),function(){});
            }
        }

    }
    jQuery.easing['Elastic']=function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
    }
    jQuery.fn.highlight = function(level) {
        highlightIn = function(options){

            var el = options.el, visible = options.visible !== undefined ? options.visible : true;

            setTimeout(function(){
                if (visible) {
                    el.css('background-color', 'rgba('+[77, 110, 255]+','+options.iteration/10+')');
                    if (options.iteration/10 < 1) {
                        options.iteration += 2;
                        highlightIn(options);
                    }
                } else {
                    el.css('background-color', 'rgba('+[77, 110, 255]+','+options.iteration/10+')');
                    if (options.iteration/10 > 0) {
                        options.iteration -= 2;
                        highlightIn(options);
                    } else {
                        el.css('background-color', '#fff');
                    }
                }
            }, 110);
        };

        highlightOut = function(options) {
            options.visible = false;
            highlightIn(options);
        };

        level = typeof level !== 'undefined' ? level : 'warning';
        highlightIn({'iteration': 1, 'el': $(this), 'color': level});
        highlightOut({'iteration': 10, 'el': $(this), 'color': level});
    };
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Hash control
    Engine.hash = {
        fns : {
            details:function(_){
                if(hashed){
                    if(lock)
                        detail.show();
                    else{
                        var id = ss(_,16,_.length);
                        lock = id;
                        hashed = 2;
                        //console.log("cache push: "+id+" total: "+_.length);
                        detail.preview(id);
                    }
                }else
                    window.location.replace(_);
/*              var id = ss(_,16,_.length);
                console.log("Preview pushed ID: "+id+" total: "+_.length);
                detail.preview(id);*/
            },
            browse:function(_){
                hashed = 1;
                Engine.API(_+"&jxt=8&jxw=b",1);
            }

        },
        api : [
                {code:"/details.php",fn:"details"},
                {code:"/browse.php",fn:"browse"}
              ],
        write:function(_){
            window.location = '#'+_;
        }
    };

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.extend(Engine.api,{
                Push:function(_){
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+_.id].des = _.des;
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+_.id].added = _.reg;
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+_.id].own = _.own;
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+_.id].tool = _.tool;
                    detail.preview(_.id);
                },
                Oarrive:function(){
                    var dataStracture = "<h2>Search results</h2><h2>Nothing found!</h2><p>Try again with a refined search string.</p>";
                    $('#torrenttable').html(dataStracture);
                    dataStracture = "";
                },
                arrive:function(_){
                    //console.log("arrive called");
                    var hd = _.head;
                    var type = [1,2,2,2,2];
                    //console.log("Bingo on head.");
                    type[hd.id] = hd.type;
                    //console.log("head set.");
                    datapipe.torrents = {};
                    //console.log("Datapipe reseted.");
                    var dataStracture = "<table id='ttable' class='movehere' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'><tr class='thead'><td>Type</td><td class='tname' onClick=\"change('"+hd.old+"s=1&t="+type[0]+"');\">Name</td><td><img src='http://static.exampleSite.me/td/tor-header.png' title='Download as .torrent file' /></td><td><img src='http://static.exampleSite.me/td/txt-header.png' title='Download as .txt file' /></td><td onClick=\"change('"+hd.old+"s=2&t="+type[1]+"');\">Com.</td><td onClick=\"change('"+hd.old+"s=3&t="+type[2]+"');\">Size</td><td onClick=\"change('"+hd.old+"s=4&t="+type[3]+"');\">Seeders</td><td onClick=\"change('"+hd.old+"s=5&t="+type[4]+"');\">Leechers</td></tr>";

                    //console.log("Bingo on start.");
                    var c = false;
                    $.each(_.torrents,function(){
                            datapipe.torrents["t"+this.id] = this;
                            //console.log("datapipe pushed: "+datapipe.torrents["t"+this.id].name);
                            c = c ? false : true;
                            dataStracture += "<tr id='tr"+this.id+"' class='trows"+(c?" tcolor":"")+"'><td><a class='_cat' id='"+this.cat+"' href='/browse.php?#/browse.php?&cata=yes&cat="+this.cat+"'><img src='"+this.cat_pic+"' border=0 /></a></td><td class='tname'><a class='T_detail' id='"+this.id+"' href='details.php?id="+this.id+"'>"+(this.New?"<b>":"")+this.name+"</b></a>"+(this.free?" <span class='tag"+this.id+" tags free'>Freeleech</span>":"")+(this.New?" <span class='tags newtags'>NEW!</span>":"")+"<br />Uploaded: "+this.added+"</td><td><a href='download.php/"+this.id+"/"+this.fname+"'><img src='http://static.exampleSite.me/td/tor-header.png' title='Download as .torrent file' border='0' /></a></td><td><a href='downloadtxt.php/"+this.id+"/"+this.tname+"'><img src='http://static.exampleSite.me/td/txt-header.png' title='Download as .txt file' border='0' /></a></td><td>"+(this.comment?"<a href='details.php?id="+this.id+"&tocomm=1'><b id='cr"+this.id+"'>"+this.comment+"</b></a>":"<zek id='cr"+this.id+"'>0</zek>")+"</td><td>"+this.size.replace(' ','<br />')+"</td><td>"+(this.seed?"<b>"+this.seed+"</b>":"0")+"</td><td>"+(this.leech?"<b>"+this.leech+"</b>":"0")+"</td></tr>";
                    });
                    $('#torrenttable').html(_.pager+dataStracture+"</table>"+_.pager);
                    dataStracture = "";
                },
                comments:function(_){
                    var dataStracture = '';

                    $.each(_.comments,function(){
                        dataStracture += datapipe.templates.comment(this);
                    });

                    $('#comment-table ul').append(dataStracture).parent().append(_.pager);
                    dataStracture = "";
                },
                commentbox:function(_){
                    $('#details').append(_+'<div id="comment-table"><ul class="clearfix"></ul></div>');
                },
                comment:function(_){
                    _['clas'] = 'hidden';
                    dataStracture = datapipe.templates.comment(_);
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment++;
                    $('#T_comment .btn span').text(datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment);
                    $('#cr'+lock).html($('#cr'+lock).text()=='0'?"<a href='details.php?"+lock+"&tocomm=1'><b id='cr"+lock+"'>"+datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment+"</b></a>":datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment);
                    $('#comment-table ul').prepend(dataStracture).children().first().slideDown().removeClass('hidden');
                    $('#tcombox').val('');
                },
                del:function(_){
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment--;
                    $('#T_comment .btn span').text(datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment);
                    $('#cr'+lock).text(datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].comment);
                    $('#li-comment-'+_).slideUp(function(){$(this).remove()});
                },
                edit:function(_){
                    $('#li-comment-'+_.id+' .comment-body').empty().html(_.box);
                    $('#li-comment-'+_.id+' .tools').prepend('<div id="'+_.id+'" class="save"></div>');
                },
                save:function(_){
                    $('#li-comment-'+_.id+' .comment-body').empty().html('<p>'+_.text+'</p>');
                    $('#li-comment-'+_.id+' .tools').prepend('<div id="'+_.id+'" class="edit"></div>');
                },
                free:function(_){
                    datapipe.torrents["t"+lock].free = _.a;
                    $('#free').replaceWith(_.link);
                    if(_.a == 1)
                        $('#tr'+lock+' .T_detail, #details #tname').after(" <span class='tag"+lock+" tags free'>Freeleech</span>");
                    else
                        $('.tag'+lock).remove();
                },
                tags:function(){
                    $(".newtagsbut").remove();
                    $('.newtags').fadeOut('slow');
                },
                files:function(_){
                    var dataStracture = "<div id='files'><table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'><tr><td width='690'>Path</td><td width='60' align='right'>Size</td></tr>";
                    $.each(_,function(){
                        dataStracture += "<tr><td>"+this.path+"</td><td align='right'>"+this.size+"</td></tr>";
                    });
                    $('#desc').after(dataStracture+"</table></div>");
                    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#files").offset().top},(nA?400:1));
                    dataStracture = "";
                }
    });
    var lock = view = lpos = ypos = hashed = 0;
    var nA = true;
    function change(datas,reloaded,move,change) {
        if(!inx(datas,"/details.php",0))
            Engine.hash.write('/browse.php?&'+datas);
        else{
            if(lock){
                //console.log("LOL YOU TROL!");
                return false;
            }else{
                var id = ss(datas,16,datas.length);
                lock = id;
                //console.log("Preview pushed ID: "+id+" total: "+datas.length);
                detail.preview(id);
            }
        }
        if(move == "yes")
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#movehere").offset().top},(nA?600:1));        
    };
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
        var _ = location.hash;
        //console.log("lock: "+lock);
        if(lock && view){
            //console.log("lock detected");
            detail.back();
            return false;
        }
        //console.log("hash came: "+_);
        if(!_ && !lock && !view){hashed=1;Engine.API("jxt=8&jxw=b"); return;}

        //console.log("hash changed: "+_);
        _ = _.replace(_.substr(0,_.indexOf('#')+1),'');
        //console.log("hash removed: "+_);
        for(i=0;i!=Engine.hash.api.length;i++){
            //console.log("loop #: "+i+" in "+Engine.hash.api.length+" loops");//
            if(inx(_,Engine.hash.api[i].code,0)){
                //console.log("loop found: "+Engine.hash.api[i].code);//
                Engine.hash.fns[Engine.hash.api[i].fn](_);
                break;
            }else{
                //console.log("loop not match: "+Engine.hash.api[i].code);//
            }
        }
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('._cat').live('click',function(x) {x.preventDefault();change('cata=yes&cat='+this.id); $("input.cats").removeAttr('checked'); $(this).prev().attr('checked','checked'); return false;});
        $('a.T_detail').live('click',function(_) {if((_.ctrlKey||_.metaKey))return true;change('/details.php?id='+this.id); return false;});
        $('.del').live('click',function() {$(this).remove();Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=cm&id='+this.id+'&a=2',1);});
        $('.edit').live('click',function() {$(this).remove();Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=cm&id='+this.id+'&a=3',1);});
        $('.save').live('click',function() {$(this).remove();Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=cm&id='+this.id+'&a=4&comment='+$('#ed'+this.id).val(),1);});
        $('#T_comment').click(function(){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#cmBox").offset().top},(nA?400:1));});
        $('#T_files').click(function(){if($(this).attr('lock')!='locked'){$(this).attr('lock','locked');Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=fl&id='+lock,1);}else{$('#files').toggle();$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("#files").offset().top},(nA?400:1));}});
        $('#T_back').click(function(){if($(this).attr('lock')!='locked'){$(this).attr('lock','locked');history.back();}});
        $('#free').live('click',function(){if($(this).attr('lock')!='locked'){$(this).attr('lock','locked');Engine.API('jxt=8&jxw=fr&id='+lock+'&a='+$(this).attr('alt'),1);}});

        $(window).hashchange();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cookie.js"></script>
<div id='T_back'><img src="/pic/back.png"></div>
<div id='T_comment'><div class='btn'><span></span></div></div>
<div id='T_files'><div class='btn'><span></span></div></div>
<br>
<div class='warp' id='mainBox'>
    <div class='warper'>
        <div id='T_table'>
            <style type="text/css">
.Browse {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none!important;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
.Browse.active{
    color:#999!important;
}
.Browse:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.Browse:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
</style>

<div id="torrenttable" style="width: 760px; display: block;"></div>
```

I am using the webBrowser control in c# to load a webpage and need to call a Jquery function that returns a string value. I got a solution to use the `InvokeScript` method, and i tried a lot , but everything got failed
I want `Webbrowser.InvokeScript()` execute `arrive:function()` but value return always null
I do not any knowledge about Jquery so I would tried
Help me, please !!!

**UPDATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

```
private void RegisterJsFunction(string function)
{
    // Your WebBrowser control and document
    var htmlDocument = this.webBrowser1.Document;
    if (htmlDocument != null)
    {
        HtmlElement head = htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptEl = htmlDocument.CreateElement("script");
        if (scriptEl != null)
        {
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement) scriptEl.DomElement;
            element.text = function;
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        }
    }
}

private string InvokeJsFunction(string functionName)
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // Your control and document 
        var htmlDocument = this.webBrowser1.Document;
        if (htmlDocument != null)
        {
            html=htmlDocument.InvokeScript(functionName).ToString();
        }
    };

    if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke(action);
    else action();
    return html;
}

   string html = string.Empty;
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, exx) =>
    {
        switch (webBrowser1.ReadyState)
        {
            case WebBrowserReadyState.Complete:
            {
                RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){Engine.api.arrive();}");
                html=InvokeJsFunction("foo"); //object reference not set to an instance of an object
                break;
            }
        }

    };
```

I updated my code follow your code( @dyatchenko ) but I got a error:"object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line html=InvokeJsFunction("foo");
please, can you help me at this error !!

**UPDATED 2!!!!!**
I updated my source html.you can check it again help me!!

Comment: The `arrive:function()` function doesn't return anything. What exactly do you want to get from this function?

Comment: This is not a problem with the webBrowser control, rather you are trying to invoke wrong. You've just taken a part of a Javascript declaration, which naturally won't work. You want to invoke a function `arrive()` with a single parameter, but that function is a part of the `Engine.api`. So you have to rethink what you're doing and what you want to actually accomplish.

In addition, it's not a "jQuery function" and it doesn't return anything...

Comment: ok.Sorry about my knowledge.So you can help me to excute $.extend(Engine.api) by InvokeScript @Sami Kuhmonen dyatchenko

Comment: @Cornor Unfortunately not, since I assume that is also not what you want to invoke. Before actually trying to invoke Javascript methods, I suggest you familiarize yourself with Javascript and explain what you are actually trying to do. Meaning not "call function X" but "there is a page Y (with link/explanation) that has this script and I want to do Z and U with it inside a WebBrowser control"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the table which is declared in the `dataStracture` variable in the `arrive` method you have to use this code:

```
RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){ Engine.api.arrive(); return $('#ttable').html(); }"); 
var html = InvokeJsFunction("foo").ToString();
```

The `html` variable is gonna be the desirable table and no NullReferenceException.

Comment: I do follow this code but still Object reference not set to an instance of an object..

Comment: I input this code in webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (s, exx) =>
            {
                switch (webBrowser1.ReadyState)
                {
                    case WebBrowserReadyState.Complete:
                    {
                        RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){ Engine.api.arrive(); return $('#ttable').html(); }");
                        html = InvokeJsFunction("foo").ToString(); 
                        //html = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("arrive:function(_)").ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

Comment: are you here @dyatchenko ? I tried more ways but still take Object reference not set to an instance of an object error !!!

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to register your javascript on your page (if your page already has it - you don't need it), like this:

```
private void RegisterJsFunction(string function)
{
    // Your WebBrowser control and document
    var htmlDocument = this.webBrowser1.Document; 
    if (htmlDocument != null)
    {
        HtmlElement head = htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        HtmlElement scriptEl = htmlDocument.CreateElement("script");
        if (scriptEl != null)
        {
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
            element.text = function;
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
        }
    }
}
```

Than, you can invoke it like this:

```
private void InvokeJsFunction(string functionName)
{
    Action action = () =>
        {
            // Your control and document 
            var htmlDocument = this.webBrowser1.Document; 
            if (htmlDocument != null)
            {
                htmlDocument.InvokeScript(functionName);
            }
        };

    if (this.InvokeRequired) this.Invoke(action);
    else action();
}
```

This is an example which shows you how to use both of this functions:

```
RegisterJsFunction("function foo() { alert('hello world'); }");
InvokeJsFunction("foo");
```

These code cuts are from my project. And I've used them a lot.
For your example you have to change you javascript code first:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyArrive(_){
         // arrive:function(_) stuff here
    }

    $.extend(Engine.api,{
                Push:function(_){ ... },
                Oarrive:function(){ ... },
                arrive: function(_) { MyArrive(); },
                comments:function(_){ ... },
                commentbox:function(_){ ... },
                comment:function(_){ ... },
                del:function(_){ ... },
                edit:function(_){ ... },
                save:function(_){ ... },
                free:function(_){ ... },
                tags:function(){ ... },
                files:function(_){... }
         });
</script>
```

And then you can invoke the desirable function with `InvokeJsFunction("MyArrive");`. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help but your example is javascript but my problem is jquery

Comment: so kind of your. you can help me with 1 example about execute jquery by invokescript use  above your code

Comment: if I follow your code. I must copy code from arrive to MyArrive but how I copy it ? Because this source jquery that I got it after i run webbrowser.navigate(url).I want to execute arrive:function cause it contain content that I want to get

Comment: @Conor In this case you can register the next function `RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){Engine.api.arrive();}");` after the browser navigation and then call it with `InvokeJsFunction("foo");`

Comment: I updated my code because I run following your code so I got error "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: this line :html=InvokeJsFunction("foo");I updated my code above. it below word UPDATED!!!!

Comment: @Cornor I think problem is in this line: `html = htmlDocument.InvokeScript(functionName).ToString();`. Try without tostring() first, as it is in the orginal version. As I've mentioned in the my first comment to this post, arrive doesn't return anything, i.e. null. And you try to call the tostring method for the null object. It causes an exception

Comment: @daatchenko:ok. I removed tostring() and code run well. but I execute Engine.api.arrive(); function because when it executed and it return table tag. content in table tag that I want to get

Comment: As I've just mentioned - arrive doesn't return anything. Here is no table tags. Check the arrive function again and decide what you want to return exactly

Comment: @Cornor if you want to get the table which is declared in the `dataStracture` variable you have to use this `RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){ return $('#ttable').html(); }");` and this `html = InvokeJsFunction("foo").ToString();` (exactly how you modified my code before) - it is gonna be the desirable table and no NullReferenceException.

Comment: I updated my source html below word **UPDATED 2!!!!!** As I said I do not any knowledge about jQuery. You can check my source html and see last line "<div id="torrenttable" style="width: 760px; display: block;"></div>
". Content in table tag inside this tag div

Comment: I follow your this code : RegisterJsFunction("function foo(){ return $('#ttable').html(); }"); and this html = InvokeJsFunction("foo").ToString(); But still null return

Comment: Try on the code from my another answer. I made a mistake in the comment. We have to call Engine.api.arrive(); first.