# Calling or executing a JQuery script in web Browser from VB.NET windows application

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am trying to automate an web page which is opened inside the Web Browser in my VB.NET windows application. While doing that, I came across a JQuery Script which needs to be called in order to execute correctly. The script is running fine in the console. Below is the script:

```
$("#filterdroid121").keydown()
```

Can someone help me to know how to call this from my VB.NET windows application please.

Comment: Web browser control has a method called InvokeScript, where you can call a script from the page by name,e.g MyWebBrowserControl.InvokeScript("ScriptName")

Comment: I have tried doing that by MyWebBrowserControl.InvokeScript("$('#filterdroid121').keydown()"), but did not work, Am i missing any syntax?

Comment: Do you have control over the html page that you are displaying? If so, try adding a pure JS Script that calls the JQuery script, then call that from InvokeScript. Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670749/how-to-execute-jquery-function-by-webbrowser-invokescript

Comment: The web page is in the client end, so I can not add anything in the page. There is a Date picker control (id = filterdroid121) in the web page. When I am passing a value to that control through console, the value is passed but it doesn't hold the value for other functions in the page to work, however if I call $("#filterdroid121").keydown() after passing the value to the control, it works in the console. I want to do the same thing through VB.NET application.